# How to include more than one column within CurrentRegion?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(2)
```

I understand that this selects column B. How would I set it to column A and B? I've tried 1, 2 and 1:2 and neither work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get columns `A:B` applied to `CurrentRegion`, the following would suffice in your case (don't forget to fully qualify your range references, e.g. with the project's sheet Code(Name) which might be `Sheet1`):

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(,2)
```

If you want to define another start column as `A:A` (e.g. the 3rd one) and resize to a double column `C:D` you might use

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(3).Resize(,2)
```

*Of course you could play around with `Intersect` and `Index` functions, too.*

Comment: Thanks T.M. How would it be incorporated into this?

`Sub AutoFill()
        Dim Ra As Range
    With Sheet2.[A1].CurrentRegion.Columns(2)
        If Application.CountBlank(.Cells) Then
            For Each Ra In .SpecialCells(4).Areas
                Ra = Evaluate(Ra(0).Address & "+ROW(1:" & Ra.Count & ")")
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub`

Comment: Assuming you are still targeting columns `A:B` and although this goes a little further than the original question, you should not only replace `With ...` with `With Sheet2.[A1].CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Resize(, 2)`, but also replace `Ra = Evaluate(Ra(0)...` with `Ra = Evaluate(Ra.Address & "+ROW(1:" & Ra.Count & ")")`.

Comment: Thanks T.M. 

So the code should appear like this?

`Sub AutoFill()
        Dim Ra As Range
    With Sheet2.[A1].CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Resize(, 2)
        If Application.CountBlank(.Cells) Then
            For Each Ra In .SpecialCells(4).Areas
                Ra = Evaluate(Ra.Address & "+ROW(1:" & Ra.Count & ")")
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub`

I tested that and it didn't do anything. The original goes through column B and fills in gaps with sequence/trend data.

Comment: Which is your targeted data range (address)? Apparently you want to fill blanks with arithmetical sequences; this might be dangerous using `CurrentRegion` if your column A disposes of blanks (xlCellTypeBlanks), too. In this case I'd try to calculate the target range in another way (see numerous posts at SO!), but this goes *far beyond* your original question  - in this case I'd suggest to consider upv./accepting and to pose a separate question describing precisely what you want to do, where you get issues - c.f. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) @Jay

Comment: Further hint: I'd prefer to use `Sheet2.Evaluate` which would qualify the address indications as belonging to `Sheet2`, whereas a simple range address would be interpreted as belonging to the active sheet which needn't be `Sheet2`. Otherwise you'd have to extend range addresses to `Ra.Address(External:=True)` @Jay